# Which channel do I use in Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies, flutter-channel

There was an announcement of Preview 1 at " 
[Announcing Flutter Release Preview 1 – Flutter – Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-release-preview-1-943a9b6ee65a)"

Download the latest beta release of the Flutter SDK In the document.
[Get Started: Install on macOS - Flutter](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/)

Latest beta release version is 0.5.1. It's updated 2 months ago...

```
$ flutter upgrade

Flutter 0.5.1 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c7ea3ca377 (9 weeks ago) • 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
Engine • revision 1ed25ca7b7
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760
```

Latest master release version is 0.5.8-pre.163.

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter upgrade

Flutter 0.5.8-pre.163 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 29410abbe7 (2 days ago) • 2018-07-27 22:10:39 -0700
Engine • revision 72a38a6b13
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.69.3.flutter-937ee2e8ca
```

**Which channel do I use in Flutter SDK?**

Answer (score 88, accepted):

From the [Flutter wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels):

> Flutter has the following channels, in increasing order of stability:
>
> ### master
>
> The current tip-of-tree, absolute latest cutting edge build. Usually
> functional, though sometimes we accidentally break things.
>
> ### dev (The dev channel was retired as of Flutter 2.8)
>
> The latest fully-tested build. Usually functional, but see [Bad Builds](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Bad-Builds)
> for a list of known "bad" dev builds. We continually try to roll
> master to dev. Doing so involves running many more tests than those
> that we run during master development, which is why this is not
> actually the same to master.
>
> ### beta
>
> Every month, we pick the "best" dev build of the previous month or so,
> and promote it to beta. These builds have been tested with our
> [codelabs](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Codelabs).
>
> ### stable
>
> When we believe we have a particularly good build, we promote it to
> the stable channel. We intend to do this more or less every quarter,
> but this may vary. We recommend that you use this channel for all
> production app releases. We may ship hotfixes to the stable channel
> for high-priority bugs, although our intent is to do this rarely.

So, use whichever channel you feel comfortable with, meets your needs and/or has whichever fixes in it you need. Start with **stable** and go from there.

Answer (score 30):

if you want to use flutter for production app then many developer and even google recommend to use stable . if you are using new feature and all feature that flutter provide that I would recommend master but not for production only for hobby project and improving your flutter skill and testing new thing that flutter provide. and not available in flutter stable.

now to know which branch you are currently using.
open terminal and type the following command.

```
flutter channel
```

It will show branch with start in front of it. that is you current branch
to change the branch you can simply use this command.

```
flutter channel ChannelName
```

use respectively channel name and hit enter and then run the below command

```
flutter upgrade
```

it will download all the require file from flutter GitHub and you will be ready to go.

all possible flutter channel are below.

> **master**
>
> The current tip-of-tree, absolute latest cutting edge build. Usually
>   functional, though sometimes we accidentally break things.
>
> **dev**
>
> The latest fully-tested build. Usually functional, but see Bad Builds
>   for a list of known "bad" dev builds. We continually try to roll
>   master to dev. Doing so involves running many more tests than those
>   that we run during master development, which is why this is not
>   actually the same to master.
>
> **beta**
>
> Every month, we pick the "best" dev build of the previous month or so,
>   and promote it to beta. These builds have been tested with our
>   codelabs.
>
> **stable**
>
> When we believe we have a particularly good build, we promote it to
>   the stable channel. We intend to do this more or less every quarter,
>   but this may vary. We recommend that you use this channel for all
>   production app releases. We may ship hotfixes to the stable channel
>   for high-priority bugs, although our intent is to do this rarely.

Answer (score 20):

Whenever you faced a strange behavior from the widgets and app like render glitch or getting white background you must change your channel to another channel  and rebuild the app with that channel.
With type this commands in terminal:

1- Current channel:

```
flutter channel
```

2- change the channel:

```
flutter channel CHANNEL_NAME
```

for example change the channel to master:

```
flutter channel master
```

Answer (score 5):

according to [Flutter build release channels](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#stable)

**stable version** is recommended for all production app releases.

Answer (score 4):

```
flutter --version
```

With this command you can get more detailed information about your development tools and their version.

- Flutter version
- channel
- git remote
- git head
- Engine
- Dart version

In my case:

> Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (7 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55
> -0700 Engine • revision ee76268252 Tools • Dart 2.8.4

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use stable Branch( Flutter version 1.0.0).

Comment: do you know what is .pre mean on flutter github ? ex: 2.7.0-3.0.pre

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE ([Flutter 2.8](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-8-d085b763d181))

There are three Flutter channels:

- stable

> The stable channel represents the highest-quality builds we have. They’re released quarterly (roughly), and are hotfixed for critical issues in between. This is the “slow” channel: safe, mature, long-term servicing.

- beta

> The beta channel provides a fast-moving alternative to stable for those who are comfortable with a faster cadence. Currently released monthly, stabilized prior to release. This is the “fast” channel. If we find that the dev channel was serving needs that the beta channel cannot currently serve, we may change how we think of the beta channel to address those needs as well (for example, accelerating the release cadence for beta or reducing the level of testing and hot fixing that we perform on beta).

- master

> The master channel is our active development channel. We provide no support on this channel, but we run a comprehensive suite of unit tests against it. This is the right channel for contributors or advanced users who are comfortable with unstable builds. On this channel, we run fast and break things (and then fix them pretty fast, too)

To check the channel you're using, run

```
flutter channel
```

To change the channel (to `beta` for example), run:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```